# HTML object tag support for LwC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, csp

I am trying use to the object tag in LWC like this

```
<template>
  <object   data="https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf"
    type="pdf"
  ></object>
</template>
```

Chrome Dev Console is displaying this:

Refused to load plugin data from 'https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'self' https://nosoftware-ability-5363-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com".

I've enable CSP for the domain - but now wondering if Salesforce doesn't support the object-src directive.

Any one successfully used  tag in LWC?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LWC framework doesn't support many HTML tags, `Object` is one of them. Refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags.htm) to get the complete list.

You can also directly refer this [github repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura/src/main/java/org/auraframework/def/HtmlTag.java) given in the above link. Any tag followed by (false) is not supported. For example, applet(false) means the applet tag isn't supported.